# Markov chain to predict LULC in GEE - is that possible?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I was wondering if is possible to build a Markov chain model do predict future land cover with a collection of classified images.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you can install third party packages in GEE, then I suggest you PySAL package. It has different Markov Chain algorithms, however it works with vector data and is has not the popular Hidden Markov model + Cellular Automata algorithm used in LULC studies.